# Numbering in pmatrix equation

Tags: numbering

```
    \par Here is an example with solving equation using the Gauss elimination method\newline
\emph{Example: Solve this  system of linear equations using the method of gaussian elimination} \cite{Analyze-math}\newline
\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{array}{lcl}   
    x  + y  - z & = & -3 \\
    -x  + 3y  + 2z  & = & 5 \\
    x + 5z  & = & 9
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
\emph{first i will start to write it in operation row}
\begin{equation}
A
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & - 1 \\
-1 & 3 & 2 \\
1 & 5 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
X
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\ y \\ z \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
B
\begin{pmatrix}
-3 \\ 5 \\ 9 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\\ 

\begin{enumerate}
    \item First you can write it in augmented matrix 
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & - 1 &|& -3\\
        -1 & 3 & 2  &|& 5 \\
        1 & 0 & 5  &|& 9
    \end{bmatrix}
     \end{equation}
    \item Add (1) to row (2) \textcolor{red}{$R_1+R_2$}
   \begin{equation}
    \begin{bmatrix}
     1 & 1 & - 1 &|& -3\\
     0 & 4 & 1  &|& 2 \\
     1 & 0 & 5  &|& 9
     \end{bmatrix}
      \end{equation}    
      \item Add -1 times row (1) to row (3)
    \[
    \begin{equation}
     \begin{bmatrix}
      1 & 1 & - 1 &|& -3\\
      0 & 4 & 1  &|& 2 \\
      0 & -1 & 6  &|& 12
      \end{bmatrix}
      \color{red}{\begin{matrix}
        \\
        \\
        R_3 - R_1\\}
        \end{matrix} 
        \end{equation}  


      \item Interchange rows (2) and (3)
      \[\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & - 1 &|& -3\\
        0 & -1 & 6  &|& 12\\
        0 & 4 & 1  &|& 2        
      \end{bmatrix}
      \color{red}{\begin{matrix}
        \\
        R_3\\
        R_2\\
        \end{matrix}}\]
      \item Add 4 times row (2) to row (3)
     \[ \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & - 1 &|& -3\\
        0 & -1 & 6  &|& 12\\
        0 & 0 & 25  &|& 50  
      \end{bmatrix}
      \color{red}{\begin{matrix}
        \\
        \\
        R_3 + 4R_2\\
        \end{matrix}}\]
      \item Multiply all terms in row (2) by -1
     \[ \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & - 1 &|& -3\\
        0 & 1 & - 6  &|& - 12\\
        0 & 0 & 25  &|& 50  
      \end{bmatrix} 
     \color{red}{\begin{matrix}
        \\
        -R_2\\
        \\
        \end{matrix}}\]
     And finally:
     \item  Multiply all terms in row (3) by 1/25
     \[\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & - 1 &|& -3\\
        0 & 1 & - 6  &|& - 12\\
        0 & 0 & 1  &|& 2    
     \end{bmatrix}
   \color{red}{\begin{matrix}
        \\
        \\
        (1/25)R_3\\
   \end{matrix}}\]
```

I use TeX Studio. I tried to give  a number to pmatrix and it did not accept. It said you've forgotten an extra '}' what is wrong with my code ? +

Comment: Welcome!  Please post a complete code that we can (try to) compile. A first visible error: in the ‘red’ matrix, the closing `}`  is after `R_3-R_1\\ `, and it should be after `\end{matrix}`.

Comment: please forgive any wrong in the post i try many solution put he did not complie

Comment: What do you mean exactly with give a number to a matrix’? Which matrix anyway?

Comment: Any news? Is my answer helpful to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After removing errors in your code (spurious `\]`, etc; see comments below your question) and use of the `nicematrix` package I rewrite your document example into the following MWE (Minimal Working Example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} % enable to write all document example on one page
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\NiceMatrixOptions{code-for-last-col  = \color{red}}
%%%%
Here is an example with solving equation using the Gauss elimination method\newline
\emph{Example: Solve this  system of linear equations using the method of Gaussian elimination} \cite{Analyze-math}
    \begin{equation}
    \setlength\arraycolsep{1pt}
\left\{
    \begin{array}{lcr}
 x +  y -  z    & = & -3 \\
-x + 3y + 2z    & = &  5 \\
 x + 5z         & = &  9
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
\emph{first i will start to write it in operation row}
    \begin{equation}
A   \begin{pNiceArray}{RRR}
 1 & 1 & -1 \\
-1 & 3 &  2 \\
 1 & 5 &  0
    \end{pNiceArray}   
 X  \begin{pNiceArray}{RRR}
    x \\ y \\ z \\
    \end{pNiceArray}    
B   \begin{pNiceArray}{RRR}
    -3 \\ 5 \\ 9 \\
    \end{pNiceArray}
    \end{equation}

    \begin{enumerate}
\item First you can write it in augmented matrix
    \begin{equation}
\begin{bNiceArray}{RRRCR}
        1 & 1 & - 1  &|& -3 \\
       -1 & 3 &   2  &|&  5 \\
        1 & 0 &   5  &|&  9
\end{bNiceArray}
     \end{equation}
\item Add (1) to row (2) \textcolor{red}{$R_1+R_2$}
    \begin{equation}
\begin{bNiceArray}{RRRCR}
     1 & 1 & - 1 &|& -3 \\
     0 & 4 &  1  &|&  2 \\
     1 & 0 &  5  &|&  9
\end{bNiceArray}
    \end{equation}
\item Add -1 times row (1) to row (3)
    \begin{equation}
\begin{bNiceArray}{RRRCR}[last-col]
      1 &  1 & - 1 &|& -3 & \\
      0 &  4 &   1 &|&  2 & \\
      0 & -1 &   6 &|& 12 & R_3 - R_1
\end{bNiceArray}
    \end{equation}
\item Interchange rows (2) and (3)
      \[
\begin{bNiceArray}{RRRCR}[last-col]
    1 &  1 & -1 &|& -3 &        \\
    0 & -1 &  6 &|& 12 & R_3    \\
    0 &  4 &  1 &|&  2 & R_2
\end{bNiceArray}
    \]
\item Add 4 times row (2) to row (3)
     \[ 
\begin{bNiceArray}{RRRCR}[last-col]
1 &  1 & -1 &|& -3  &           \\
0 & -1 &  6 &|& 12  &           \\
0 &  0 & 25 &|& 50  & R_3 + 4R_2
\end{bNiceArray}
      \]
\item Multiply all terms in row (2) by -1
     \[
\begin{bNiceArray}{RRRCR}[last-col]
1 & 1 & -1  &|&  -3 &           \\
0 & 1 & -6  &|& -12 & -R_2      \\
0 & 0 & 25  &|&  50 &           
\end{bNiceArray}
    \]     
     \item  And finally multiply all terms in row (3) by 1/25
     \[
\begin{bNiceArray}{RRRCR}[last-col]
1 & 1 & -1  &|& - 3 &           \\
0 & 1 & -6  &|& -12 &           \\
0 & 0 &  1  &|&   2 & (1/25)R_3
\end{bNiceArray}
    \]
\end{enumerate}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

From your document example follows, that you number only first five matrices. Above MWE follows this numbering. If you like to have numbered all matrices, than in the rest ones you need to replace `\[` and `\]` with `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}` respectively.

Use of `bNiceArray` defined in the `nicematrix` package enable more shorter way to write matrices with labels to rows, which indicate performed operations.

[image]

For above result you need to compile MWE at least twice.